# SQL Server - get a list of linked servers

Tags: sql-server

I am running the following code:

```
EXEC sp_linkedservers
```

Which returns:

[image]

However, I don't have any linked servers created on that instance.
So, how I get a true list of linked servers?

Thanks

Comment: Technically the local server is a linked server (called a loopback server). I would use `sys.servers` though, not a procedure.

Comment: I see. So, for the Instance with one linked server it will return two rows?

Comment: That procedure? Yes. But again, I suggest you use [the catalog view, `sys.servers`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-catalog-views/sys-servers-transact-sql). The output should make it obvious which columns you can use to filter out entries there that aren't really linked servers.

Comment: No, I meant select * from sys.servers.

Comment: Yes, same. Do you have an instance with at least one linked server, where you could test for yourself? Compare that to, say, `SELECT * FROM sys.servers WHERE is_linked = 1;`.